# SQLite WASM How to load existing DB from url

Tags: javascript, sqlite, webassembly

I have an API endpoint that serves an SQLite database. I want to load this DB in a web app and then query it. Persistence is not needed, as I'm not writing to it.

Creating a new DB works well:

```js
new sqlite3.oo1.DB();
```

However, neither the constructor nor any other function before takes an existing DB as arguments. The constructor can take a filename as argument, but that doesn't seem to work. It just fails without even triggering a HTTP request.

sql.js has a constructor like this:

```js
new SQL.Database(new Uint8Array(buffer));
```

That works, but I can't use sql.js, because it doesn't have FTS5.

How do I load an existing DB? Shouldn't that be easy?

Comment: This might help, => https://blog.ouseful.info/2022/04/06/compiling-full-text-search-fts5-into-sqlite-wasm-build/

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to load an existing db in the original sqlite-wasm from sqlite.org.

You may replace the demo1 function from the demo-123 with the following code:

```
const demo1 = function(sqlite3, dbUrl, immutable=false) {
    
    fetch(dbUrl)
    .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
    .then(arrayBuffer => {
        if (!immutable) {
            arrayBuffer.resizeable = true;
        }
        const p = sqlite3.wasm.allocFromTypedArray(arrayBuffer);
        const db = new sqlite3.oo1.DB();
        let deserialize_flags =
            sqlite3.capi.SQLITE_DESERIALIZE_FREEONCLOSE;
        if (!immutable) {
            deserialize_flags |= sqlite3.capi.SQLITE_DESERIALIZE_RESIZEABLE;
        }
        const rc = sqlite3.capi.sqlite3_deserialize(
            db.pointer, 'main', p, arrayBuffer.byteLength, arrayBuffer.byteLength, deserialize_flags);
        db.checkRc(rc);
        xplorer.setDb(db);
        db.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t(a,b)");
    });
};
```

Comment: Oh, wow! I'll test your approach, but if it works, then I'll accept this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work: I compiled sql.js myself, adding FTS5 support.

It's quite easy. Just add the FTS5 option to [the Makefile](https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js/blob/6288273fc9348a7d10866639d6bf53a7a5c1ac2d/Makefile#L25):

```
--- a/Makefile
+++ b/Makefile
@@ -23,6 +23,7 @@ SQLITE_COMPILATION_FLAGS = \
        -DSQLITE_DISABLE_LFS \
        -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 \
        -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS \
+       -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS5 \
        -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=0 \
        -DSQLITE_ENABLE_NORMALIZE
```

And then `make`. On my system, I hade some issues with sha3sum not being present and emscripten trying to write to a readonly filesystem, but both issues can be solved easily. The resulting wasm and js files can be found in the `dist/` directory afterward.

There is a proposal on the repo to enable it by default, but it seems to have stalled: [sql-js/sql.js#199](https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js/pull/199)

Comment: if you dont want to modify the makefile, you could use autoreconf and then invoke `./configure --enable-fts5`

Comment: @TheFool do you know if there is a way to just build .a(static lib) instead of wasm file. I want the supporting JS files and a .a which I can link in my main wasm file. I have tried doing --enable-static option in configure file but it does not seem to help.

Comment: @Anil, I am not sure what you do there with wasm and stuff. However, you might be able to use `sqlite.{c,h}` as they are described in the very first paragraph here https://www.sqlite.org/custombuild.html. Technically you should include sqlite.h in your wasm thingy, and then build them both together i.e. `gcc wasm.c sqlite.c ...`